# Get XY position of caret position in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, position, jtextarea, caret

Actually, i have already ask this question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864368/get-xy-position-from-caret-position-in-jtextarea/18864392?noredirect=1#18864392). But, i'm making mistake. I haven't already get the solution.

First, at the question before, i can get Rectangle with

```
Rectangle rectangle = textArea.modelToView( textArea.getCaretPostion() );
```

I'm also get X and Y position.

I'm creating a editor that can add new Text Area each i press Enter key. XY position with code above always give same return in every Text Area. Look my code.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class forquestion extends JFrame {

    Container textAreaBox;
    LinkedList<JTextComponent> textArea;
    int nameTA;

    public forquestion() {
            int nameTA = 0;

            textArea = new LinkedList<>();

            textAreaBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
            textAreaBox.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
            addLine();
            this.add(textAreaBox);
            this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            forquestion app = new forquestion();
            app.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    }

    public void addLine () {

            JTextComponent temp_ta = createTextComponent();
            textArea.add(temp_ta);
            textAreaBox.add(textArea.getLast());
            textAreaBox.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
    }

    protected JTextComponent createTextComponent() {
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea("test");

            /*if (count%2==0)
                            ta.setForeground(Color.red);
            else
                            ta.setForeground(Color.GREEN);*/

            ta.setFont(new Font("Courier New",Font.PLAIN,16));
            ta.setLineWrap(true);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            ta.setName(Integer.toString(nameTA));
            nameTA+=1;

            basicKey("ENTER", enter, ta);

            ta.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
                    public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent ev) {
                            try {
                                    taMousePressed(ev);
                            } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                                    Logger.getLogger(forquestion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                    }
            });

            return ta;
    }

    public void basicKey(String s, Action a, JTextArea ta) {

            ta.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(s), s);
            ta.getActionMap().put(s, a);
    }

    Action enter = new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    addLine();
            }
    };

    private void taMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent ev) throws BadLocationException {
            int now_focus = Integer.parseInt(ev.getComponent().getName());
            int _caret;
            _caret = textArea.get(now_focus).getCaretPosition();
            Rectangle rectangle = textArea.get(now_focus).modelToView(_caret);
            double x = rectangle.getX();
            //int xc = textArea.get(now_focus).getLocation().x;
            double y = rectangle.getY();
            //int yc = textArea.get(now_focus).getLocation().y;
            //double h = rectangle.getHeight();
            //double w = rectangle.getWidth();
            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(y);  
            //System.out.println(xc);
            //System.out.println(yc);  
            //System.out.println(h);
            //System.out.println(w);
            System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

My code will print XY position each time you press a Text Area. But, the display always same in every text area. (Try to make many Text Area and give some text) Btw, it just simple code. You need change the window frame size for update the new text area after you press enter key..hahaha.

So, my question is: How can i get the XY position of caret (text cursor) in any Text Area. I want to display JPopmenu there. :)

I hope this question clear for you. Thx before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Rectangle` reported back is relative to the text area, where it's 0x0 position is the top, left corner of the component.

If you use something like...

```
popup.show(textArea.get(now_focus), rectangle.x, rectangle.y + rectangle.height);
```

Where `popup` is a `JPopupMenu`, it will make the required translations to the screen itself.

Now.  Having said that.  Personally, I would prefer to use the popup API support provided by Swing.  This is going to mean needing to create a custom component that extends from `JTextArea` to achieve it...

```
public class MyPopupTextArea extends JTextArea {
    /*...*/
    public Point getPopupLocation(MouseEvent evt) {
        Rectangle rectangle = textArea.get(now_focus).modelToView(_caret);

        Point p = rectangle.getLoction();
        p.y += rectangle.height;

        return p;
    }
}
```

Then, based on your needs, you can use `setComponentPopup` to provide a shared instance of the `JPopupMenu` or, if required, create a custom `JPopupMenu` for each instance of the custom editor and use `setComponentPopup` as you see fit...no messing about with mouse listeners ;)

Comment: I see. Thx for solution.Btw, could you give me your full code for my problem? At least, a constructor of your or the code for add Jpopmenu to panel or frame. I'm still learn JPopMenu. Each time i add it to container, it will cover other component.

Comment: You don't add a JPopupMenu to a component (normally). You should use setComponentPopup to associate a popup with a component, or, if you have special needs use JPopupMenu#show to show a popup. Think of more like a special window then a component. You could take a look at [Brining up popup menu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for more details...

Comment: It's make sense to me. Thanks anyway :D