# How can i get caret position in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, popup, caret

I want to have the X and Y position of the caret of my JTextPane.

Here is what i have now :

```
Rectangle2D rectangle = textPane.modelToView2D(textPane.getCaretPosition());
popupMenu.show(frame, (int)rectangle.getX(), 80 + (int)rectangle.getY());
```

This code is from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18864392/14911094

But there is a problem with it!

This is ok but i also have a scroll pane with the JTextPane (this is code for the JFrame constructor):

```
editorPane = new JTextPane();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorPane);
this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));
this.add(scrollPane);
```

And the code to show the popupmenu is being called by another function in a diff class  :

```
popupMenu.removeAll();
for (String item : stringItems)
    popupMenu.add(new JMenuItem(item));
Rectangle2D rectangle = editorPane.modelToView2D(editorPane.getCaretPosition());`
popupMenu.show(frame, (int)rectangle.getX(), 80 + (int)rectangle.getY());
popupMenu.updateUI();
```

So when i get down to lower lines the popup moves out of screen as the rectangle.getY() is very high.

How can i solve this problem!

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
public class Try {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
        JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        textPane.setText("SOME RANDOME TEXT FHDFFHNGHNFKJ!");
        textPane.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                try {
                    Rectangle2D rectangle = textPane.modelToView2D(textPane.getCaretPosition());
                    popupMenu.show(frame, (int) rectangle.getX(), 80 + (int) rectangle.getY());
                } catch (Exception ex) {}
                frame.requestFocus();
                frame.requestFocusInWindow();
                textPane.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });
        String itms[] = {
            "HI",
            "Hello"
        };
        ArrayList < String > items = new ArrayList < > (Arrays.asList(itms));
        for (String item: items)
            popupMenu.add(new JMenuItem(item));
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.setSize(900, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't down vote, but:: *i think this much is enough for a mimial reproducible example* - a [mre] implies we can copy/paste/compile and test to see the described behavour. We can't do that with the posted code. I would guess the popup should not be relative to the frame. You would need to consider the viewport location.

Comment: @camickr it is impossible for me to give the code for the frame as these are in different classes as this is a quite big project but still i will try to give

Comment: @AndrewThompson check it now but please try to understand the project is big and the code is split into multiple classes and i am trying to pull the parts that is responsible for the popup ans show it in the question

Comment: @camickr is it now ok?

Comment: We don't care about your application. Your question is about displaying a popup on a JTextPanel. So you need a JFrame with a JScrollPane and a JTextPane and a popup. The point of the [mre] is to simplify the code to make sure you actually understand the problem you are trying to describe. You should be able to create the MRE in about 20-30 lines of code. Here is an example of an MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743427/jtable-right-click-popup-menu/16744590#16744590

Comment: @camickr i added what you had asked for is it ok now?

Comment: I suggested `the popup should not be relative to the frame`. In the link I provided as an example MRE I showed how I have done this in the past.

Comment: @camickr I don't have a mouse listener at all neither I want it to be a mouse listener as the mouse is nowhere in the scene I want the menu to show up under the carpet like in the way normal ides shows completions I have got an algorithm generating the completions and you can consider whenever the method to show the pop-up menu is called the stringItems is filled with the predictions and also if the predictions are not available the menu is hidden{setVisible(false)} so how can I do this with a mouse listener?

Comment: My suggestion was that you should NOT be using the "frame" as the invoker of the popup, but instead the text pane. You have an "event". In your case a KeyEvent. Whether you use a MouseListener or a KeyListener, the event will contain the source of the event. The example shows how to use the source of the event as the invoker of the popup menu, not the frame.

Comment: @camickr i am using the textPane as the invoker as it is invoked for every key pressed the frame is no where involved frame is just for the textpane to show up its not involved in this at all

Comment: The `popup.show(...)` method is using the frame. So the popup is displayed relative to the frame which is why it appears so far below the frame.

Comment: @camickr I think the problem with my code is that it's returning X y coordinate of caret with respect to the textPane this when I scroll down the y position is more than the screen width

Comment: @camickr let me try to change that to textpane 8nstead of the frame

Comment: @camickr changing it t frame solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr is the comments!

The problem with my code was that I was showing the popupmenu with respect to the frame instead of the textPane

Here would be a solution.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Try {
    public static final int CARET_HEIGHT = 15;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
        JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        textPane.setText("SOME RANDOME TEXT FHDFFHNGHNFKJ!");
        textPane.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                try {
                    Rectangle2D rectangle = ((JTextPane)(e.getSource())).modelToView2D(textPane.getCaretPosition());
                    popupMenu.show(((JTextPane)(e.getSource())), (int) rectangle.getX(), CARET_HEIGHT + (int) rectangle.getY());
                } catch (Exception ex) {}
                frame.requestFocus();
                frame.requestFocusInWindow();
                textPane.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });
        String itms[] = {
            "HI",
            "Hello"
        };
        ArrayList < String > items = new ArrayList < > (Arrays.asList(itms));
        for (String item: items)
            popupMenu.add(new JMenuItem(item));
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.setSize(900, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: As I suggested in my link you should be getting the text pane from the source of the KeyEvent. Learning to use the information in the event will allow you to create more generic and reusable listeners.

Comment: @camickr i added it